# Ошибка C2440 в VisualStudio 2019

Tags: c++, указатели, шаблоны-с++, sfml, enum-class

Типы kp::InputField/Button/Timer* не конвертируются в ReturnClass*. Что здесь не так? Непонятно.

```
template <class ReturnClass>
static ReturnClass* createObject(kp::ObjectType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case kp::ObjectType::InputField:
            return createInputField();

        case kp::ObjectType::Button:
            return createButton();

        case kp::ObjectType::Timer:
            return createTimer();

        default:
            return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Образно говоря, вы хотите "впихнуть невпихуемое" — возвращать указатели на разные типы. Понимаете, параметр шаблона — это при компиляции некоторый *конкретный* тип. А вы, похоже, хотите, чтоб эта функция во время работы возвращала указатели на разные типы. А так нельзя.

Comment: @Harry, а как можно реализовать подобную задумку? Создавать шаблоны для каждого из типов или есть более эффективный и правильный вариант?

Comment: Все зависит от того, что именно вы хотите. Но обычно вот такие ветвления a la ваш switch для создания объектов говорят о не лучшем проекте...

Comment: Разве `ReturnClass` недостаточно, чтобы определить, какой класс создавать? Зачем еще и енум передавать?

Comment: может этот энум приходит от какого то парсера и по нему нужно создавать объект нужного класса.

Comment: @KoVadim, исходя из значения енама должна вызываться необходимая функция, создающая класс, и этот класс в теории должен возвращаться из createObject

Comment: Спасибо за "помощь"

Comment: Может, имеет смысл эти классы наследовать от общего и возвращать указатель на этого общего предка?

Comment: @Mikhailo, они унаследованы от одного и каждый раз при создании приходится делать уродливый огромный каст. Я хотел от этого избавиться

Comment: Вы приняли ответ с `variant` - но там же тоже каст нужен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если тип неизвестен на этапе компиляции, то вернуть разные типы нельзя. Темплейты тут бессильны.

Можно так:

```
variant<TypeA*, TypeB*, void*> createObject(kp::ObjectType type)
```